# How do you concat columns from two dataframes in pairs?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with the same index values and column headers these are called '*Actuals*' and '*Targets*'. With the code below I end up with both in the same df but placed next to each other.

```
actuals = pd.read_excel('PDS Monthly')
targets = pd.read_excel('Targets')

result = actuals.reset_index(drop=True).merge(targets.reset_index(drop=True), left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(result)
```

| Actual Col A | Actual Col B | Target Col A | Target Col B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val a1 | val b1 | val x1 | val y1 |
| val a2 | val b2 | val x2 | val y1 |

What I am after is the columns being paired together so they look like the table below.

| Actual Col A | Target Col A | Actual Col B | Target Col B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val a1 | val x1 | val b1 | val y1 |
| val a2 | val x2 | val b2 | val y1 |

In total there are 45 cols in total but they all follow this naming pattern. I think that I need to iterate over the cols to add them in one after the other, any assistance would be great.

Comment: What are real columns names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea is sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with key parameter for values after first space:

```
result= result.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.str.split(n=1).str[1])
```

Or you can zip original columns names for expected order:

```
cols = [y for x in zip(actuals, targets) for y in x]

result = result[cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to invert the two components and pass it to [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)'s `key` parameter:

```
result = retuls.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.str.replace(r'(.+) Col (.+)',
                                                               r'\2 \1', regex=True))
```

Output:

```
  Actual Col A Target Col A Actual Col B Target Col B
0      val a1       val x1       val b1        val y1
1      val a2       val x2       val b2        val y1
```

###### How it works

it internally creates a temporary string with the two components reversed:

```
df.columns.str.replace(r'(.+) Col (.+)', r'\2 \1', regex=True)

# Index(['A Actual', 'B Actual', 'A Target', 'B Target'], dtype='object')
```

*NB. you might need to adapt the regex depending on your real column names. Here this assumes a name like `<part1> Col <part2>`.*